# Which Eclipse for Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, 64-bit, version, 32-bit

Should I use 32-bit Eclipse or 64-bit Eclipse for Android development? Im on a MacBook Pro (Core 2 Duo). Does it matter which version for Android coding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java virtual machine makes the difference between 32bit an 64bit mostly invisible to you. So no, it won't matter much.

The Android SDK will run on either :)

Comment: Sweet. Does it matter if I choose Carbon or Cocoa?

Comment: They only differ slightly in look and feel. But since Apple is pushing Cocoa, that would be my choice.

Comment: I bought a mac recently myself and had similar questions. I found articles at the following site useful: http://blog.zvikico.com/2009/10/installing-eclipse-galileo-on-mac-os-x.html

Comment: Im installed Galileo (64bit Cocoa) - no problems so far.

Answer (score 0):

The general recomendation is to go with the J2EE version because it's packaged with the XML packages you'll want.  If you go with the standard or other version you will just spend more time getting all those packages when you install the Android plug-in.  Make sure to run upgrade software until it doesn't find anything else in Eclipse before installing the plug-in.

Comment: What packages are these? Is it really much harder to download them seperately?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, make sure you get the Cocoa version. The Carbon was almost impossible to work with with big projects (100% cpu, 100% stack use, slow "Open Type", slow "Open Resource")